# .htaccess redirect rules with mapped urls and generic rules

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to get an .htaccess rule set to match certain requirements:
some url are mapped on to one (using Redirect) to external urls.

I need the root path to get to root path of another external domain.

urls that are not mapped before, get to second external domain maintaining current path.

Here's what i've tried:

```
Redirect /current/url/from-domain http://newDomain1.com/new/url
Redirect /current/url/from-domain-2 http://newDomain1.com/new/url-2

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://newDomain2.com/$1 [R]
```

I just made possible to accomplish two of the three conditions I need. So it should be:

mapped urls -> external domain 1 mapped url.

```
http://myCurrentDomain.com/current/url/mapped -> http://externalOne.com/new/url
```

not mapped urls -> external domain 2 + old url.

```
http://myCurrentDomain.com/{anything} (not mapped anything) -> http://externalTwo.com/{anything}
```

root path -> external domain root path.

```
http://myCurrentDomain.com -> http://externalTwo.com
```

I'm just a noob working with .htacces, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a way:

```
// For any mapped route
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/path/to/orl/url.html$
RewriteRule ^ httph://myNewDomain1.com/new/path [L,R]
// endfor

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ http://myNewDomain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
```

This is still not as good solution as wanted, because i have to Rewrite about 1k url, but there will not be more new url.

The problem here is that urls does not follow a clear structure and are not easily relational to new urls...